# How to preserve and object instantiated in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Supposing I have the following

```
public class Foo {
   private Map<Integer,SomeObject> myMap;
   public Foo() {
      this.myMap = new HashMap<Integer,SomeObject>();
   }

   private class Runner implements Runnable {
       public void run() {
            SomeObject someObj = new SomeObject();
            Foo.this.myMap.put(10,someObj);
            //'soObj' will always be null upon retrieval later...
       }   
   }
}
```

If I create a thread with a Runnable of type 'Runner' and start the thread, it will run.
In the run method, I simply create an instance of 'SomeObject' and place it in the map of the outer class.
However, when I attempt to get a value from 'myMap' later on, the 'SomeObject' instance will always be null. I can't understand why as I have placed a reference into the map 'myMap' which still lives on in the heap after the thread finishes. Is there a way around this?!

Thanks very much

Comment: No it won't be null. If you think you are seeing that you have some other problem to solve.

Comment: Ok so. There's probably something missing in my logic somewhere. So you're saying that when the thread dies, the 'SomeObject' instance will still be on the heap as I've passed a reference to it in to 'myMap'? In other words, it won't be marked for garbage collection? Thanks

Comment: First, are you sure the Runner actually ran? (Like some Thread executed it?) If so, then it put the object in the map -- so there's a path from the outermost Foo instance to the Map to the SomeObject. Then, if the Foo still exists -- there's a reference to it on the stack or in global state -- SomeObject will be reachable, and not GC'd.

Comment: Please don't format code in your question like that. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Short version: just indent the code with 4 spaces, or use `Ctrl+K` or click the `{}` button.

Comment: Apologies about the formatting. I wasn't sure how to do it correctly. Yes, I am sure the runner actually ran. I'll have to dig deeper to try and find out what's happening. I have a feeling, it may be to do with concurrency as I know that HashMaps are not internally synchronized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem with the way your objects are instantiated. It should be:

```
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Thread thread = new Thread(foo.new Runner());
    thread.start();
```

Comment: You were right... This fixed my problem. I was instantiating my thread like so - new Thread(...).start(); I changed it to - Thread t = new Thread(foo.new Runner()); t.start(); What's the difference?!

Comment: Heh, didn't know such syntax! +1

Comment: At the end the doc says: `To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class.` http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing from one Thread and reading from another, you'll have to think about concurrenct access and visibility. As your code-snipplet does not show any sign of that, I guess that might be the problem. In any case you have to fix it first, before digging deeper into the problem.

You'll have to do some sort of synchronization like [synchronized-blocks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), [read-write-locks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) or special concurrent classes like [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). Make sure you get yourself familiar with those techniques, especially a ConcurrentHashMap can be tricky to handle depending on how you want to use it.

Edit: For a simple synchronized Map you might use [synchronizedMap()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) from the great Collections-class, but be careful with iterations on those Maps (see the corresponding javadoc for details).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at the FutureTask in java.util.concurrent - it can return an object.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/